# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actioncontroller

As a common pattern I see `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error to appear after deployment to my heroku app.

I am using rails (6.0.1).

My session store config looks like:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_rails_app_session'
```

Any particular reason I would be getting this error? And how to fix it?